# installing rmagick gem on ubuntu 20.04 WSL on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm installing rmagick gem on ubuntu 20.04 WSL on windows 10, I got the error below

```
make "DESTDIR="
compiling rmagick.c
compiling rmdraw.c
compiling rmenum.c
compiling rmfill.c
compiling rmilist.c
compiling rmimage.c
rmimage.c: In function ‘Image_gray_q’:
rmimage.c:7552:32: error: ‘IsGrayImage’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘DrawImage’?
 7552 |     return has_attribute(self, IsGrayImage);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                DrawImage
rmimage.c:7552:32: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make: *** [Makefile:245: rmimage.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

any help please

Comment: Which version of rmagick are you installing? I found this and it seems the issue should be gone in version 7.0.10-33  https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/1228

Comment: thanks Mike, upgrading to version 7 solved the problem, please add it as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like installing a newer version will work, try 7.0.10-33.

The reason being that there were some mixed up compilation flags in earlier versions, for details see github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/1228

Comment: @FDI here you go!

Answer (score 3):

please try installing libMagickWand

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

[rmagic github issue](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/1228#issuecomment-700260450)